# SQL Pivot Using three tables

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am running into some trouble trying to pivot some data out of SQL.

I have three tables that will comprise the data.

Table 1: (Clause)
  -Clause
  -ClauseName

Table 2: (Process)
  -Id
  -ProcessName

Table 3: (RELProcessClauses)
  -ProcessId
  -Clause
  -WeightedValue

Ultimately, I am looking to have a matrix of data that is Clause, ClauseName down the left, ProcessName across the top and the Weighted value to correspond between Process and Clause.

Not sure if this will make much sense.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I suspect you realize this isn't a great question because you are probably unsure how to communicate this stuff. No worries mate, [this article](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) does a great job explaining what to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the three tables and use `PIVOT` on it. You can run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
c.Clause, 
c.ClauseName,
p.ProcessName,
pc.WeightedValue
from RELProcessClauses pc
JOIN Clause c on pc.clause = c.clause
JOIN Process p on pc.ProcessId = p.id
) x
PIVOT (
  SUM(WeightedValue) 
  FOR ProcessName IN ([ProcessName1], [ProcessName2], [ProcessName3])
) as pvt
```

Output table:

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| Clause | ClauseName  | ProcessName1 | ProcessName2 | ProcessName3 |
+--------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|      1 | ClauseName1 |           10 |           15 |           30 |
|      2 | ClauseName2 |           15 |           20 |           30 |
|      3 | ClauseName3 |           20 |           20 |           30 |
+--------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The query/output works on the demo tables created using the query below:

```
CREATE TABLE Clause (
 Clause int,
 ClauseName varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Process (
 Id int,
 ProcessName varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE RELProcessClauses (
 ProcessId int,
 Clause int,
 WeightedValue int
);

INSERT INTO Clause VALUES
(1, 'ClauseName1'), 
(2, 'ClauseName2'),
(3, 'ClauseName3');

INSERT INTO Process VALUES
(1, 'ProcessName1'), 
(2, 'ProcessName2'),
(3, 'ProcessName3');

INSERT INTO RELProcessClauses VALUES
(1, 1, 10), 
(1, 2, 15),
(1, 3, 20),
(2, 1, 15),
(2, 2, 20),
(2, 3, 20),
(3, 1, 30),
(3, 2, 30),
(3, 3, 30);
```